# Do the irrationals form a closed subset of R?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across a theorem from Rudin's book that, *the subsequential limits of a sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space X form a closed subset of X.* However, I also just learnt that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. And my confusion arises because the rationals and irrationals form a partition of the set of $\mathbb{R}$, which would imply that the irrational numbers cannot be an open nor a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

If we let $\mathbb{R}$ to be our metric space X from the above Theorem, where all subsequential limits of a sequence of rational numbers form a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which will be the set of irrationals, does this mean that the set of all irrational numbers should form a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of irrationals (and rationals) in $\mathbb{R}$ is neither open nor closed. They're both not open because any neighborhood around a point contains both rational and irrational numbers. Since they are each other's complements, this means neither can be closed.

Your mistake is here: $"\textbf{where all subsequential limits of a sequence of rational numbers form a subset of } \mathbb{R}$ $\textbf{which will be the set of irrationals}$"

A subsequential limit of a sequence of rational numbers is not necessarily irrational. For instance, consider the sequence $0,0,..$

Comment: I see what you mean, is my mistake that: all irrational numbers are a subsequential limit of rationals, but the converse, that all subsequential limits of rationals are irrational is not true?

Comment: and since all subsequential limits of the rationals is not equal to the set of irrationals, there is no supposed contradiction

Comment: @TJ.Kim correct